# cannot import name 'T5Tokenizer' from 'transformers.models.t5'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, simpletransformers

As you see in the following python console, I can import `T5Tokenizer` from `transformers`. However, for `simpletransformers.t5` I get an error:

```
>>> from transformers import T5Model, T5Tokenizer
>>> from simpletransformers.t5 import T5Model, T5Args                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simpletransformers/t5/__init$
_.py", line 2, in <module>
    from simpletransformers.t5.t5_model import T5Model
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simpletransformers/t5/t5_mod$
l.py", line 20, in <module>
    from transformers.models.t5 import T5Config, T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer
ImportError: cannot import name 'T5Tokenizer' from 'transformers.models.t5' (unknown locatio
n)
```

Comment: I ran into this issue a while ago and was able to get my code running by installing an [older version](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/issues/963#issuecomment-766777994) of `transformers`. [Others suggest](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/issues/963#issuecomment-803650650) uninstalling and reinstalling `transformers` and `simpletransformers`.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Before posting this, I did what you suggested, and I even restarted the computer. Anyways, the problem existed. Now that I checked it, it's working!! In between I installed `t5`, and it might be installed or uninstalled something that was effective!

Answer (score 1):

just try installing older version of transformers:

```
!pip install transformers[torch]==4.3
```

Comment: probably the exclamation mark is not needed?

Comment: it is required for google colab